# (Unity) Как я могу рассчитать силу воздействия на объект со стороны SpringJoint

Tags: unity3d, физика

У меня есть 2 объекта, на одного из них есть компонент SpringJoint а другой объект(объект2) соединен с этой SpringJoint.Очевидно что при перемещении объекта2, сила влияния пружины на объект2 увеличивается. Хотел узнать есть ли способ как то рассчитать эту силу??.

Comment: Дополни свой вопрос, напиши что пытаешься сделать, есть у меня ощущение, что тебе не нужна эта сила.

Comment: о привет) - это для расчета траектории полета снаряда...

Comment: У меня в коде, который я в чате прикладывал есть пример. Запоминаешь начальную позицию перетаскивания -> начальная позиция - конечная позиция = вектор направления куда пулять -> длину этого вектора можешь использовать в своей формуле расчета траектории.

Comment: окей, спасибо, попробую